# Is it possible to host dache cache on IIS?

Tags: dache

I'm developing a Web App with Dache, Thanks the author for the fantastic library.
Unfortunately, I have a big problem with it.
In previous version of 1.5.6, it was worse. but in 1.5.6 it's better but still I get The following exception:

```
There are no reachable cache hosts available. Verify your client settings and ensure that all cache hosts can be successfully communicated with from this client.
```

In developing, I get the exception after 2 or 3 times build, and I have to restart cache service and stop IIS Express to remove the exception.
In the web app after some hours the clients disconnect from cache service. and I have to restart the cache service and web sites to remove the exception.

I hosted dache on windows service.

I think the problem is for comunications between dache host and dache clients.
 
So, Is it possible to host dache cache on IIS like a WCF service instead of windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host Dache in your own process using the Nuget package. More information available on [the Dache wiki](https://github.com/ironyx/dache/wiki/Quick-Start#host-in-your-own-process):